# Disallow Manual Filtering

Tags: list, web-part, filter

I'm using SharePoint 2010.  I have a webpart page with a Choice Filter webpart and a list webpart connected to the filter.  Everything is setup and functioning correctly.  But...

If the user manually filters the list using the column heading dropdown options, then my choice filter is completely ignored until the user clears the manual filter on the column.  Is there a way (w/o using SP Designer) to not allow the user to filter the list via the column headings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to a content editor web part on the page. 
Change the list title in the code.

If you run into any issues, check the dev tools to make sure you are grabbing the correct properties while finding the jQuery header elements.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("table[summary='List title goes here'] th[role='columnheader']").removeAttr('onmouseover');

    $("table[summary='List title goes here'] th[role='columnheader'] div").removeAttr('sortfields');
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: That worked with a little tweaking, I had to remove the [role='columnheader']